# Registros duplicados laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estimados estoy tratando de llenar una tabla con datos de otras tablas pero se duplican los registros:
por un lado tengo la tabla `super`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado tengo la tabla `sitmans`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por ultimo la tabla que debo llenar se llama `volins` y es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde marca la flecha se me empiezan a duplicar los valores, donde `cod_rodal` es el código que traigo de la tabla `super`, `edad` es la resta de `emax` y `emin` de la tabla `sitmans` donde tengo qe verificar que el sitio y manejo sean los mismos

este es mi código en el controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = DB::table('super')->select('codigo','sitio','manejo')->get();
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        $datasitman = DB::table('sitmans')->where([['sitio','=',$d->sitio],['manejo','=',$d->manejo]])->get();
        if(count($datasitman)>0){  //para que solo tome los que encuentre
            $volInv = new VolInv;
            $volInv->cod_rodal = $d->codigo;
            $volInv->edad = $this->calculaEdad($datasitman);
            $volInv->tipo = "r";
            $volInv->prod1 = 30;
            $volInv->save(); 
    }   
    }    
    return view('/mensajes/mensajeImport');     
 }        
public function calculaEdad($array){
    $datasitman = $array;
    foreach ($datasitman as $dato) {
        $edad = $dato->emax - $dato->emin; 
        return $edad;
    }
}
```

este es mi código en la vista:

```
<a href="{{ url('/volInv') }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">VolInv</a>
```

y en mi ruta:

```
Route::get('volInv', 'VolInvController@store');
```

Comment: Solo para asegurar... ¿Haces `truncate table` cada que haces las pruebas?

Comment: si :S la vacío cada vez

Comment: en la columna created_at se ve que se crean al mismo tiempo :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código parece correcto, sin embargo te haré algunas refactorizaciones que optimizen y puedan solucionar tu problema.

```
$data = DB::table('super')->select(['codigo', 'sitio', 'manejo'])->get();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    if($sitman = DB::table('sitmans')->where('sitio', $d->sitio)->where('manejo', $d->manejo)->first()) {
        Vollnv::firstOrCreate([
            'cod_rodal' => $d->codigo,
            'edad' => $dato->emax - $dato->emin,
            'tipo' => 'r'
            'prod1' => 30
        ]);
    }
}
return view('/mensajes/mensajeImport');
```

Comment: si me funcionó :D ahi cambie $dato que sería $sitman, y funciona ok! muchas gracias :D